# Fetch state from Redux action on page load

Tags: node.js, redux, electron

I'm working on an app that requires Twitch OAuth. I have the authentication side working.

Now when I navigate to the main page after authentication, I need it to fetch the user's information. E.g. email, display name, user id, etc and then display some of it on the page.

`Home.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import styles from './Home.css';
import routes from '../constants/routes.json';
import { fetchUser, user } from '../features/home/homeSlice';
export default function Home() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const User = useSelector(user);
  return <div>You are logged in as {User.display_name}! <button onClick={() => dispatch(fetchUser())}>Load</button></div>;
}
```

(Currently the only way I can get it to work is by clicking the button, which works)

`homeSplice.ts`:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { RootState, AppThunk } from '../../store';
import axios from 'axios';
import Config from '../../lib/Config';

const config = new Config();
const accessToken = config.getAccessToken();

const homeSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'home',
  initialState: {
    user: {
        id: 0,
        login: null,
        display_name: null,
        type: null,
        broadcaster_type: null,
        description: null,
        profile_image_url: null,
        offline_image_url: null,
        view_count: 0,
        email: null
    }
  },
  reducers: {
    userSuccess: (state, action) => {
      state.user = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { userSuccess } = homeSlice.actions;

export const fetchUser = (): AppThunk => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    axios
      .get('https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/validate', {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `OAuth ${accessToken}`,
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        const client = response.data;
        axios
          .get(`https://api.twitch.tv/helix/users?id=${client.user_id}`, {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
              'Client-ID': client.client_id,
            },
          })
          .then((response) => {
            const user = response.data.data[0];
            dispatch(userSuccess(user));
          });
      });
  };
};

export default homeSlice.reducer;

export const user = (state: RootState) => state.home.user;
```

This all works fine, but only when I click the "Load" button. I don't want this. I need my page to somehow execute `fetchUser()` on page load. I have tried converting this to a React Component and doing it through `componentDidMount()` through information I found online - but most of them tell you to call `this.props.fetchUser()`, which does not work for me, because the actions aren't appearing under `this.props`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what type of component you're using. If you're using functional component, then check out `useState` and `useEffect`. If you're using class component and declare fetchUser as a class method, then of course this.props.fetchUser won't work, because this.props are states that are passed from parents. Just call this.fetchUser or fetchUser if declared outside of the class component.

Comment: `useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchUser());
  });` seems to work, but it's doing it in an infinite loop.

Comment: You need to set an empty dependency. useEffect will re-render the component if any of the dependencies change. Do useEffect(callback, []).